# An SMTP To address is required to send a message/Argument Errror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mailchimp

[ArgumentError at /contacts
An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MLi2.jpg)

Good Day Guys,I am having trouble debugging this myself and have consumed so much time I needed your help and explanation as to how why it didn't work.

Things I did already:
1.Added gem 'binding_of_caller'
2.bundle install

goal: 
Is when a visitor submit a contact form it supposed to send me a email message automatically.

My woes/confusion:

1.How do you set your email in secrets.yml or put your email wherein you configured the contact form request directly to your email
2.What I did is put
  to:myemail.com > secrets.yml both in production and development 
3.Am I right?

Please explain this to me as I am going in depth on ruby on rails.

Comment: The Rails guides on how to set up email is pretty clear Binding of caller has nothing to do with email. Show 1. At what point is the Mailer supposed to act (sometimes this is in the model, sometimes in the controller. Show us both the controller for and the model for wherever you are capturing the visitor information. Does it populate the :users table? Start with posting these and the exact error message you're getting, and you'll get help from me or someone else.

Comment: ok sir thank you I will

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a mailer first.

```
rails g mailer example_mailer
```

app/mailers/example_mailer.rb This file will be generated by this line.

Then you need to create a method in your mailer where u can define whom to send mail. you can give direct email id or you can take it from database. As in my given example u need to pass user to this method and it will send email to that user's email.

```
  def sample_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Sample Email')
  end
```

Create a HTML template for how your mail will look

> app/views/example_mailer/sample_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      Sample mail sent using smtp.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you need to configure your smtp in /config/environments/production.rb or /config/environments/development.rb whichever environment you are using.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :user_name            => 'username@gmail.com',
 :password             => 'Gmail password',
 :authentication       => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Then you need to trigger your mail action any any method from where you are sending mails.

```
ExampleMailer.sample_email(@user).deliver
```

Comment: Thank you sir , still on the learning curve , however I need to read the basics again . I noticed the problem already and will resolve this issue later on as I progress.Thank you for all the help